# Would I need a loop in this situation? New to javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops

Not really positive on this. I have a showHide loop running to display and change some hidden DIVs once different nav links are clicked, as well as a second loop to change the background color on the "active" link that is clicked to display each DIV.

Obviously link #1 and DIV #1 are connected and so on and so forth. I need the link #1 to be displayed as "active" and have the background color to show that DIV #1 is the active one being displayed. Right now the background color will not show up until the link is clicked.

That adds wierd functionality, because if you click link #1, the background color shows up and stays there after click, but the DIV never changes because obviously is it the active one already.

Do you guys think I need another link? I can't find what i need for this. Maybe I'm searching the wrong thing? I'm sure it's some simple javascript, but I don't know it.

Comment: I have no clue as to what I just read... :p Some examples would come in handy, or even better a jsfiddle link.

Comment: Perhaps you need to toggle in your link click event. That isn't a loop. On click, if backgroundcolor = yellow, change it to white else if it's white, change it to yellow. That's an "if", not a loop.

Comment: Would you please share some of your codes or even simulate your issue via JsFiddle.net, then we can help you much better :-)

Comment: Basically, here is an image of the links. As you can see, the healthcare link has a background color. I need healthcare to have a background color when the page loads, not just after it is clicked. Remember though, when another link is changed, the background color must go away and switch to another link. I already have that functionality in place via a loop. Here is the image: [link](legacycreativestudio.com/test.png)

Comment: Sorry for being so confusing guys. I'm new to javascript and I couldn't display my code for NDA reasons. But i got it so thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. write a function to loop and hid all the divs and reset the color (or background color) of your links,
2. in the click events of the links add a function that takes a parameter [as func1(this)],
3. in event function first call the above described function and then change the color (background color) of the same link whose object you take as parameter and change the visibility of the related div.

eg:
[a link] to the example on jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/hHwZJ/3/)

Comment: Basically, here is an image of the links. As you can see, the healthcare link has a background color. 

I need healthcare to have a background color when the page loads, not just after it is clicked.

Remember though, when another link is changed, the background color must go away and switch to another link. I already have that functionality in place via a loop.

Here is the image: [link](http://legacycreativestudio.com/test)

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you mike , but you could set the **link #1 and DIV #1** active by the inline style which would change by the function or the event later on.